# PHP unset session not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

My PHP script to unset session variable is not working.

I need to call a PHP file `destroy.php` which contains code to unset session variable from ajax, everything is working fine except session clear.

I'm posting my code for clearing session variable, please point out my error.

jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "SubmitReview.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,

                        success: function(response)
                        {
                            $.fn.destroySession();
                            $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);
                            $('body').children(':not(div.ErrorMessageContainer)').fadeTo(500, 0.1);
                            $('div.ErrorMessageContainer').html(response).fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                $('body').children(':not(div.ErrorMessageContainer)').fadeTo(500, 1);
                            }, 5400);
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                window.location.href = "Thanks.php";
                            }, 5600);
                        }
                    });

$.fn.destroySession = function()
            {
                $.post("Destroy.php");
            }
```

`destroy.php`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['MN']))
{
    $_SESSION['MN'] = array();
    unset($_SESSION['MN']);
}

?>
```

Comment: Combining sessions and ajax sometimes makes it so that session doesn't work. If you're going to use ajax, pass in through parameter instead of using session.

Comment: session started? plus `$.post("Destroy.php");` and `destroy.php` are two different animals on a NIX system.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Worked like a charm sir....Thank you so much.... What I was thinking is that when I am clearing session then why to again start session....but your solution helped me .....Thank you tons....

Comment: @KushAcharya You're very much welcome, *cheers*

Comment: @frosty Thank you sir for your feedback....I will definitely keep this mind...

Comment: @KushAcharya *"why to again start session"* - Because, `session_start();` is required to reside in the file even though you want to unset it (that's just how they built it at PHP.net). I left a link in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, you did not start the session and is required to be inside all files using sessions.

Therefore, add `session_start();` at the top and underneath your opening PHP tag.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

> *"why to again start session"* - Because, `session_start();` is required to reside in the file even though you want to unset it (that's just how they built it at PHP.net).

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['MN']))
{
    $_SESSION['MN'] = array();
    unset($_SESSION['MN']);
}
```

Comment: @luweiqi hehe thanks for the typo fix. I type a bit too fast at times. My fingers get all *lkasdfkfdakdsdfjajsd* lol.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're awesome sir...cleared my doubts...again **tons of thank you**......

Comment: @KushAcharya You're most welcome Kush, glad to have been of help, *cheers!*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, this was helpful, but one doubt; if we add the session_start at the beginning, then isset($_SESSION) would always be true, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Neo it wouldn't always be true, since it's set inside a condtional statement, `if(isset($_SESSION['MN']))` as per what is in the answer. However, if someone were to do and if this is what you're talking about and using something like: `$var = isset($_SESSION['var']);` then that would qualify as a session array always be considered as being set, which in turn stands to fail and is not proper syntax for checking if a session array is set.

Answer (score 0):

Put session_start() on first line.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['MN']))
{
    $_SESSION['MN'] = array();
    unset($_SESSION['MN']);
}
```